# How do I check if a character in an inputed sentence is a character in a given string?

Tags: python

I am a totally new programmer, learning python for the first time so sorry if my question isn't very clear and I am not using the correct computer science terminology. What I am trying to do is count the number of vowels in an inputed sentence without having to write out:

```
if i== 'a' or i == 'e' or i == 'i' or i == 'o' or i == 'u' or i == 'A' or i == 'E' or i == 'I' or i == 'O' or i == 'U'`
```

How do I check if the character char is inside the string 'aeiouAEIOU' using only one line? Could someone please tell me what am I doing wrong here?

This is my code so far.

```
def count_vowels (sentence):
    vowels = 0
    for char in sentence:
        if char == 'aeiouAEIOU'.split():
            vowels += 1
    return vowels
```

Answer (score 1):

We can trim that down to something like:

#### Code:

```
def count_vowels(sentence):
    return sum(char in set('aeiouAEIOU') for char in sentence)
```

[`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) is a quick way to add up sequences.  This works because `True` is `1` and `False` is `0`.

#### Test Code:

```
print(count_vowels('jkdbfjksdbvuihejsdvknweifn'))
```

#### Results:

```
5
```

Comment: Another approach: `sum(1 for char in sentence.lower() if char in 'aeiou')`

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `==` with `in` and then check if the character is in the vowels:

```
def count_vowels (sentence):
    vowels = 0
    for char in sentence:
        if char in 'aeiouAEIOU':
            vowels += 1
    return vowels
print(count_vowels('Hello World!!!'))
```

Output:

```
3
```

## Shorter Way

Try creating a list comprehension:

```
def count_vowels (sentence):
    return len([i for i in sentence if i in 'aeiouAEIOU'])
print(count_vowels('Hello World!!!'))
```

Output:

```
3
```

Comment: Is there an easier way to do it without using split() on the 'aeiouAEIOU' string and still maintaining only 1 line for the if statement?

Comment: @RoryDaulton thanks for letting me know i edited my answer, i think now it's better